# Building and installing Duine recommender and Dunie-movielens system by using maven in netbeans

Tags: java, windows, maven, netbeans-7, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to install duine recommender system in my netbeans in windows 7 64bit machine, every time I tried to build it I got this error:

cd D:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\duine-movielens-4.0.0-RC1-maven; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" "\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\"" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath org.duineframework.movielens.MovieLensRecommenderClient" "-Dexec.executable=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe" process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
Scanning for projects...

Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.duineframework:duine-movielens:jar:4.0.0-RC1
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ org.duineframework:duine-framework:4.0.0-RC1, C:\Users\ANM.m2\repository\org\duineframework\duine-framework\4.0.0-RC1\duine-framework-4.0.0-RC1.pom, line 125, column 12
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 86, column 21
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin is missing. @ line 27, column 12
The expression ${parent.artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.parent.artifactId} instead.
The expression ${parent.artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.parent.artifactId} instead.
'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin is missing. @ line 112, column 12
'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ line 128, column 12

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

---

### Building Duine MovieLens 4.0.0-RC1

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 14 resources

[compiler:compile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[exec:exec]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recommender' defined in class path resource [spring-recommender.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'predictionEngine' while setting bean property 'predictionEngine'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topN' defined in class path resource [spring-predictors.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ratingModel' while setting bean property 'ratingModel'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ratingModel' defined in class path resource [spring-profiles.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ratingModelDAO' while setting bean property 'ratingModelDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ratingModelDAO' defined in class path resource [spring-profiles.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'recommender.sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recommender.sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-recommender.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ratingModel' defined in class path resource [spring-profiles.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ratingModelDAO' while setting bean property 'ratingModelDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ratingModelDAO' defined in class path resource [spring-profiles.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'recommender.sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'recommender.sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-recommender.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

### at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveRef

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 6.022s
Finished at: Fri Mar 27 16:50:22 GMT 2015

### Final Memory: 10M/153M

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project duine-movielens: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I tried to find solution but most solutions are in eclipse or linux while I'm using windows and netbean .Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
e<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>org.duineframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>duine-framework</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-RC1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.duineframework</groupId>
<artifactId>duine-movielens</artifactId>
<name>Duine MovieLens</name>
<url>http://www.duineframework.org</url>
<version>4.0.0-RC1</version>
<description>A demo application for the Duine Recommender</description>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>duine-sourceforge-site</id>
        <url>scp://shell.sourceforge.net/home/groups/d/du/duine/htdocs/duine-movielens</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://duine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/duine/proper/movielens/tags/duine-movielens-4.0.0-RC1</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://duine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/duine/proper/movielens/tags/duine-movielens-4.0.0-RC1</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:svn:https://duine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/duine/proper/movielens/tags/duine-movielens-4.0.0-RC1</url>
</scm>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <templateFile>../${parent.artifactId}/src/site/site.vm</templateFile>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../${parent.artifactId}/target/site/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>
                        src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
                        </descriptor>
                    <descriptor>
                        src/main/assembly/maven-assembly.xml
                        </descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>          
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager.exe</executable>

                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                maven-project-info-reports-plugin
            </artifactId>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>license</report>
                        <report>issue-tracking</report>
                        <report>project-team</report>
                        <report>dependencies</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.duineframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>duine-recommender</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- in case mysql is used -->
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- in case hsqldb is used -->
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>jcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>servletapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>servletapi</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xmlrpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlrpc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>berkeleydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>berkeleydb</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I hope to have help on this I'm really stuck here :(